# No duplicate files: Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: objective-c, linker-errors

I've gotten the error "linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"
on my program, and I'm not sure what to do.
Yes, I know there are other questions, I read them and tried the different solutions, but I think the problem is different.
I've checked both in the project files stored on my desktop and in the one in Library/Developer, but I can't find any duplicate classes even though thats what it tells me.

I can give you my code too, if you need it, but hopefully I won't have to.
Thanks! :D

Full error report:
Ld /Users/ethen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjAllele-asuihysyexvjvmdsgfladthghavb/Build/Products/Debug/ProjAllele normal x86_64
    cd /Users/ethen/Desktop/ProjAllele
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.8
        /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -L/Users/ethen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjAllele-asuihysyexvjvmdsgfladthghavb/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/ethen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjAllele-asuihysyexvjvmdsgfladthghavb/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/ethen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjAllele-asuihysyexvjvmdsgfladthghavb/Build/Intermediates/ProjAllele.build/Debug/ProjAllele.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ProjAllele.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -framework Foundation -o /Users/ethen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjAllele-asuihysyexvjvmdsgfladthghavb/Build/Products/Debug/ProjAllele

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Organism in:
    /Users/ethen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjAllele-asuihysyexvjvmdsgfladthghavb/Build/Intermediates/ProjAllele.build/Debug/ProjAllele.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
    /Users/ethen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjAllele-asuihysyexvjvmdsgfladthghavb/Build/Intermediates/ProjAllele.build/Debug/ProjAllele.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Organism.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_Organism in:
    /Users/ethen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjAllele-asuihysyexvjvmdsgfladthghavb/Build/Intermediates/ProjAllele.build/Debug/ProjAllele.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
    /Users/ethen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjAllele-asuihysyexvjvmdsgfladthghavb/Build/Intermediates/ProjAllele.build/Debug/ProjAllele.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Organism.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Organism in:
    /Users/ethen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjAllele-asuihysyexvjvmdsgfladthghavb/Build/Intermediates/ProjAllele.build/Debug/ProjAllele.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
    /Users/ethen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjAllele-asuihysyexvjvmdsgfladthghavb/Build/Intermediates/ProjAllele.build/Debug/ProjAllele.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Pea.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_Organism in:
    /Users/ethen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjAllele-asuihysyexvjvmdsgfladthghavb/Build/Intermediates/ProjAllele.build/Debug/ProjAllele.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
    /Users/ethen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjAllele-asuihysyexvjvmdsgfladthghavb/Build/Intermediates/ProjAllele.build/Debug/ProjAllele.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Pea.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Plant in:
    /Users/ethen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjAllele-asuihysyexvjvmdsgfladthghavb/Build/Intermediates/ProjAllele.build/Debug/ProjAllele.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
    /Users/ethen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjAllele-asuihysyexvjvmdsgfladthghavb/Build/Intermediates/ProjAllele.build/Debug/ProjAllele.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Pea.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_Plant in:
    /Users/ethen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjAllele-asuihysyexvjvmdsgfladthghavb/Build/Intermediates/ProjAllele.build/Debug/ProjAllele.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
    /Users/ethen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjAllele-asuihysyexvjvmdsgfladthghavb/Build/Intermediates/ProjAllele.build/Debug/ProjAllele.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Pea.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Organism in:
    /Users/ethen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjAllele-asuihysyexvjvmdsgfladthghavb/Build/Intermediates/ProjAllele.build/Debug/ProjAllele.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
    /Users/ethen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjAllele-asuihysyexvjvmdsgfladthghavb/Build/Intermediates/ProjAllele.build/Debug/ProjAllele.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Plant.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_Organism in:
    /Users/ethen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjAllele-asuihysyexvjvmdsgfladthghavb/Build/Intermediates/ProjAllele.build/Debug/ProjAllele.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
    /Users/ethen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjAllele-asuihysyexvjvmdsgfladthghavb/Build/Intermediates/ProjAllele.build/Debug/ProjAllele.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Plant.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Plant in:
    /Users/ethen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjAllele-asuihysyexvjvmdsgfladthghavb/Build/Intermediates/ProjAllele.build/Debug/ProjAllele.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
    /Users/ethen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjAllele-asuihysyexvjvmdsgfladthghavb/Build/Intermediates/ProjAllele.build/Debug/ProjAllele.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Plant.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_Plant in:
    /Users/ethen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjAllele-asuihysyexvjvmdsgfladthghavb/Build/Intermediates/ProjAllele.build/Debug/ProjAllele.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
    /Users/ethen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjAllele-asuihysyexvjvmdsgfladthghavb/Build/Intermediates/ProjAllele.build/Debug/ProjAllele.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Plant.o
ld: 10 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Did you import "Plant.m" instead of "Plant.h" in "main.m" ?

Comment: It would be useful if we could see the imports in the main, pea, and plant .h and .m files. Right now there isn't enough information to do anything more than speculate, really.

Comment: I added Pea.h to main.m (Pea is the most subbed class). @BenPious, sure thing, just a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a comment you wrote: "main.m imports Pea.h Pea.h imports Plant.m, ...".

There is the problem. "Pea.h" must import "Plant.h", not "Plant.m".

Otherwise the `Plant` class in "Plant.m" is compiled in *all source files* that import "Pea.h",
for example in "main.m", leading to the duplicate definition errors.